# Does Cohen's Kappa sample size calculation need a check for "true kappa" feasibility?

Tags: r, reliability, cohens-kappa

The sample size computation

```
require(irr)
N.cohen.kappa(rate1 = 0.9, rate2 = 0.5, k1 = 0.7, k0 = 0.5, alpha=0.05, power=0.8, twosided=FALSE)
```

successfully runs and gives a result ... but shouldn't it fail with some kind of warning?

Consider the pattern of missing values in Table 1 and the second sentence of the left-bottom paragraph of the second page [here](http://www.ime.usp.br/~abe/lista/pdfGSoh9GPIQN.pdf), which reflect an upper bound for Kappa when rate1 is not the same as rate2. For example, Kappa must be less than 0.2 if rate1 = 0.9 and rate2 = 0.5, right?  So shouldn't the function fail when I use those two rates with k1 $ = 0.7$, since that "true kappa" is not feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should fail with a warning.  The reasons cited in the OP are correct; here I'll simply derive an upper bound for kappa that proves the point.

Define several "true" population level parameters:

- $r_1=$ rate1 and $r_2=$ rate2 are the rates at which the two raters select the target category
- $\pi_e$ is the expected rate of agreement between the two raters that you get if you assume the operate independently.  We can write this explicitly in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$.  The probability they both select the target category is $r_1 r_2$ and the probability they both don't select the target category is $(1-r_1)(1-r_2)$.  Thus, in total, $\pi_e = r_1 r_2 + (1-r_1)(1-r_2) = 1 - r_1 - r_2 + 2r_1 r_2$.
- $\pi_0$ is the rate of agreement between the two raters, i.e., the fraction of cases in which they agree with each other.

Now we have

$$\kappa = \frac{\pi_0 - \pi_e}{1- \pi_e} = \frac{\pi_0 - 1 + r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2}{r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2}$$

Observe that the maximum rate of agreement between the two raters on selecting the target category is $\min(r_1, r_2)$.  Similarly, the maximum rate of agreement on not selecting the target category is $\min((1-r_1), (1-r_2))$.  In total,
$\pi_0 \leq \min(r_1, r_2) + \min((1-r_1), (1-r_2))$.

Assume, WLOG, that $r_1 \geq r_2$.  Then $\pi_0 \leq r_2 + 1-r_1$.  Thus

$$ \kappa \leq 
\frac{(r_2 + 1-r_1) - 1 + r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2}{r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2} = \frac{2r_2 - 2r_1 r_2}{r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2}=
2r_2 \frac{1 - r_1}{r_1 + r_2 - 2r_1 r_2} $$

So, what happens when we plug in $r_1 = 0.9$ and $r_2 = 0.5$ as in the OP? Then $\kappa$ can't be greater than $0.2$.  Indeed, the power computation in the OP rests on the false premise that the true kappa is 0.7, and so it would be desirable for the function to throw a warning.